# "while setting conditions to retain its ability to use Syrian territory"

Tags: meaning

*The Islamic Republic of Iran has conducted an extensive, expensive, and integrated effort to keep President Bashar al-Assad in power as long as possible **while setting conditions to retain its ability to use Syrian territory and assets to pursue its regional interests should Assad fall**.*

http://www.understandingwar.org/report/iranian-strategy-syria

I am not not able to understand the part in bold in the above sentence. The core of the statement is in my opinion "while setting conditions should Assad fall" which I find in terms of both grammar and meaning a little bit awkward. Is it the concessive clause? Does it mean that although the Iranian regime supports Assad it would be in its interest to do the opposite?

Comment: I think it means that the author does not know how to write clear English. I will leave it for an expert to untangle the sentence.

Comment: It is an odd turn of phrase, but while I was trying to think of how to reword the idea, I came to understand why they chose it. Iran is [hedging their bets](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hedging "7. to mitigate a possible loss by counterbalancing (one's bets, investments, etc.") but it's difficult to explain that succinctly and give the information of what they want to be able to still do if Assad falls. I might say "while working to secure its ability to...". but I don't think it's exactly the same sense of creating a hedge against Assad losing power.

Comment: ...while setting conditions to preserve its ability to use Syrian territory and assets in order to continue to pursue its regional interests if Assad should fall.  Not sure what the vague "setting conditions" means, and would have to read the article.  Normally, when we *set conditions*, it is with another party with whom we are entering into an agreement, and it means to make demands or set requirements that the other party must meet.

Comment: After reading the article, I'd gloss **setting conditions** with "maneuvering".

Comment: So it means the very opposite than I thought. The fall of the Assad regime would cause the decrease of the political influence of Iran in the territory. – I overlooked that "shoul Assad fall" is the inversion. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @bart-leby It is required of political science writing that it cram as many ideas as possible into complicated clauses without intervening commas in order to maintain the impression that the author's logic is impenetrable to the generalist reader and thus sufficiently weighty to warrant publication in obscure journals in furtherance of grant proposals.

Comment: @TRomano I think maneuvering is a really good way to put it. I wish I had though of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... while setting conditions to retain its ability to use Syrian territory and assets to pursue its regional interests should Assad fall.

That's because it's not well-written.  Someone didn't use his editor, or more likely, had a contract for a certain word count.

Better would have been something like, "The Islamic Republic of Iran has conducted an extensive, expensive, and integrated effort to keep President Bashar al-Assad in power as long as possible, while at the same time maintaining its influence over regional territory and assets should he fall."  Then it's clearly understood that Iran is playing both sides.